# MVVM, getting data with threads + tests

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tdd

I was thinking how I could test a following scenario: I have a viewmodel that is responsible for getting data, it also holds some other informations, like parameters responsible for visibility of some elements and whatnot, that a view can bind to. Let's assume it looks like this (simplified scenario):

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<MessageViewModel> Objects { get; set; }
    private List<MessageDto> _someData; 

    private bool _loadingIndicatorVisible;
    public bool LoadingIndicatorVisible 
    { 
       get { return _loadingIndicatorVisible; } 
       set { _loadingIndicatorVisible = value; OnPropertyChanged(); 
    }

    private bool _isLoading;

    public void StartGettingData()
    {
        if (_isLoading)
            return;

        _isLoading = true;
        LoadingIndicatorVisible = true;

        var taskForGettingData = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _someData =  WebService.GetMessages());
        taskForGettingData.ContinueWith(task => EndGettingData(), TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);
    }

    public void EndGettingData()
    {
        _isLoading = false;
        LoadingIndicatorVisible = false;

        //convert _someData to ObservableCollection<MessageViewModel> - implementation irrelevant
    }
}
```

Now I would like to write a following test:

```
void ShouldHaveLoadingIndicatorVisibleWhenLoadingMessages() { /* ... */ }
```

How should I approach this? What makes me confused here is a use of threads. Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a curious title that you have there... it seems to have nothing to do with your question. It says *MVVM, getting data with threads + tests*, but your question is about just testing a UI property named `ShouldHaveLoadingIndicatorVisibleWhenLoadingMessages`. So this is *not* about getting data with threads.

I make this point because testing data access and testing the UI are two completely different things. If you just want to test the UI, then you should have a look at what the [UI Automation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN has to offer you.

However, if you just want to test if a particular property is being set, regardless of its effect in the UI, then you can just use a normal test for your view model. The secret to making a testable application is to interface all relevant functionality.

By this, I mean that you could have a `ThreadManager` class that handles all multi-threading for you. You'd then need an `IThreadManager` interface and a `MockThreadManager` that implements the `IThreadManager` interface, but *actually* executes the code on the main UI thread *instead* of normal functionality provided by the `ThreadManager` class. Having said that, running code in different threads is *not* a problem when testing, as long as results are correctly amalgamated..

More importantly, would be a `DataProvider` class with its `IDataProvider` interface and `MockDataProvider` 'fake' data provider, so that you can test the view models *without touching the actual data in the database*.